# Add a tableview cell at the last row of a section

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to add a tableview cell at the last row of a section. I searched in the web and can't find a suitable solution for my problem.

My app is based on Master-Detail application.

When I add a new cell, I want to be at the last row but it is always happening at the first row of the section.

The problem is because of the following method as it has newIndexPath with already defined row, normally it is at row 0. I can't trace where is the source of assigning newIndexPath and call this method.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me inserting in a section:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPath:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[mydataarray count] inSection:[SECTION_NUMBER]] withRowAnimation:..]
```

So count specifies where I want to place it in the section and SECTION_NUMBER is your section of course.
sorry if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi yes, this is what I am looking for. But in which method should I call this insertRowsAtIndexPath? I use Maser-Detail application and it has didChangeObject method with newIndexPath. newIndexPath is already assigned with row and section. If I replace newIndexPath with my desired location (say the last row), there is conflict with the cell from the first row as it is shifted automatically to the last row (the row I want to insert).